# Global js variable not passed in $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I declared a variable server_url in a .js file when I alert it in my file.js I can see it.

The problem is when I launch the ajax request, it seems like the value of server_url doesn't get seen and it goes directly to the error message. But, when I hard code the variable in the HTML file with script tags and I remove the include of the config.js file from the HTML, the ajax request can read it without a problem.

Any explanation or help?
Here are more or fewer parts of my code.

config.js

```
var server_url = 'https://url.com';
```

file.js

```
$('#app_status_account').click(function() {

    alert(server_url);

    $.ajax({
        url: server_url + '/my_web_service',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            client_phone: $('#client_phone_number').val(),
            PIN_code: $('#pass').val()
        },
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert('Request couldn't be done');
        }
    });
});
```

index.html (the include part; I tried it in the head and even in the end before closing the body tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/config.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is it definitely at global scope?  Just to be sure, remove the `var` and change it to `window.server_url = "https://url.com"`

Comment: @Lotus91 could you update your question and add the error you are getting?

Comment: ^^ This.  It's most likely not the url that's at fault, but a server error.

Comment: When the url is directly in the html file, everything works fine.

Comment: @KФ, i see the "error" from the alert.

Comment: @Lotus91 And what does this error say?

Comment: You're not capturing the actual error.  Change the error handler to `function(jqXHR, textStatus, error)` and the next line to `alert(error);` then let us know what is alerted.

Comment: After removing `$.ajax..`, you will get alert result of `server_url`. So not get alert result is caused by error code in `$.ajax..`

Comment: @Archer, alert(error) never shows...

Comment: Then there's no error.  In your code, is there a comma after the closing brace of the `success` callback?  There isn't in the code above.

Comment: yes there is in my actual code

Comment: @Archer your answer was right! I checked, something went wrong with the server while i was testing :D

Comment: Glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try declaring server_url with

```
window.server_url = 'https://url.com';
```

it sounds like when you declare it you're not doing it in the global scope. Also you could try putting `alert(1)` right AFTER you declare it, then in your function before you do the ajax call you could put `alert(server_url)` and make SURE you see the first alert BEFORE the alert in your ajax function.

Comment: the alert AFTER the declaration and the one BEFORE the ajax function are showing with no problem. Still not working window.server_url

Comment: right after you declare server_url put an alert `alert(window.server_url)` do you see that? Also, in your ajax method refer to the global as `window.server_url` and not just `server_url`, maybe you have another `server_url` variable in scope at that point somehow

Comment: I did exactly what you just said and still the same, i replaces server_url with window.server_url.

Comment: and to be sure, the alert in your ajax function shows up AFTER the alert that you put when you're declaring your variable? in your ajax function if you put `setInterval(function(){ console.log(window.server_url) }, 1000)` and open up your console do you eventually see the correct value being printed out?

Comment: something went wrong with the server while i was testing. You were right from the beginning. Thank you! :)